# How to extract the characters from a string that are inside parentheses?

Tags: python, pandas

Picture of the DataFrame:

[image]

I have one column named contracting and another named contractor inside a DataFrame.

I need to divide, for example, the column contractor, into 2 new columns: one column containing the Fiscal number that is inside the parenthesis and another column containing all the rest (the description).

Example:

```
Contractor: Meo(504615947)
```

I need that it becomes:

```
Contractor_Name: Meo and Contractor_Number:504615947
```

I tried to do this:

```
proc_2013[['contractor_description', 'contractor_NIF']]= pd.DataFrame(proc_2013['contractor'].str.split(('('),1).tolist())

proc2013['contractor_NIF'] = proc2013.contractor_NIF.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Problem 1:

I can have a name description inside a parenthesis as well, followed by the number that I am trying to extract.

Problem 2:

Sometimes, if the contractor is from a foreign country, it has a letter in the beginning of the Fiscal Number (not only numbers as I assumed at first, using my second line of code).

All Fiscal Numbers have 9 digits.

Comment: Please give a proper [mcve], in text form.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post. I will keep your suggestions in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i could understand your question, this can be a possible solution,

```
df['contractor_name']=list(map(lambda x : x.split('(')[0],df['con']))
df['contractor_number']=list(map(lambda x : x.split('(')[-1][-10:-1],df['contractor']))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Akash! But I still have a problem. I have the following string: "Trabalhadores em Funções Públicas (ADSE) (600000303)""
My goal is to split this into two new columns: Contractor_Name: "Trabalhadores em Funções Públicas (ADSE) " and Contractor_Number: 600000303. Using the solution you provided, I obtain Contractor_Number: "ADSE)" . Can you still help me, please?

Comment: i have updated the code to give you required contractor_number, please confirm if you need (ADSE) as well in your contractor_name?

Comment: It's working now exactly as I wanted. Thank you so so much Akash for your great help!!!!

Comment: No, Thanks. Didn't knew that. Keep Coding :)

Comment: It seems to have worked now. I was able to click in the arrow to vote +1. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could change `\d` to `\w` for any alphanumeric like:

```
proc2013['contractor_NIF'] = proc2013.contractor_NIF.str.extract('\((\w+)\)')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Franco! Your comment helped me to solve my second problem. I still need to understand what to do when I have something like:

Trabalhadores em Funções Públicas (ADSE) (600000303). I am getting ADSE as the fiscal number instead of 600000303.

Comment: Welcome! It would be good if you clarify which are the inputs that you are having trouble with with examples.

Comment: Akash already helped me to solve the problem. Thanks again Franco for the help and sorry if I wasn't very clear!